# Function to check if user is under a certain age returning true, when it should be returning false

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a function that checks a users age based on the date of birth given. This is on my user model.

Date of birth is 1995-02-23

```
public function age()
    {
        return $this->date_of_birth->diffInYears(\Carbon\Carbon::now());
    }
```

When I run this in tinker against a certain user, I get the correct age. 23.

I also have a function to check which checks a users age, to determine which section of the site they can access.

```
public function Youth(){
  if($this->age() == 16 || 17){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

This is returning true on the above user in tinker when it should be returning false, as the user's age is 23. Any obvious issues with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   public function Youth(){
      if($this->age() == 16 || $this->age() == 17){
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are not comparing `17` to anything. Try:

`if($this->age() == 16 || $this->age() == 17) {`

Currently, you are just checking "if age is 16 OR **true**". This is because your conditional check for `17` alone will always evaluate to `true` (because it is positive).

Answer (score 0):

The OR boolean operator does not work like you are doing.
**We need to specify OR conditions differently even when we are checking for the same variable**

Example:

```js
if($this->age() == 16 || 17){
```

This is wrong way of specifying the OR condition using || operator

Rather

```js
if($this->age() == 16 || $this->age() == 17){
```

you should use the above code where you full specify the consition differently.

Comment: Its updatad now